# ASP.NET vNext, multiple HomeControllers in areas

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm having a look at ASP.NET 5 and MVC 6 and I'm using the default starter template. I have now set up an area in which I would like to have an "HomeController". So there will be the default HomeController which isn't placed in an area and then there will be the HomeController in Areas/MyArea.

The following configuration in Startup.cs does obviously not work:

```
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "areaRoute",
                template: "{area:exists}/{controller}/{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

It gives me this error message:

> AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched. The following
>   actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied:
>
> MyProject.Controllers.HomeController.Index
>   MyProject.Areas.MyArea.Controllers.HomeController.Index

In earlier MVC versions you should be able to solve it by defining namespaces to the routes config like discussed in this blog post: http://blog.falafel.com/duplicate-controller-names-aspnet-mvc-areas/

Though this is not working for me. If I add `namespaces: new string[] { "MyProject.Controllers" }` to the default route I'm getting the following error:

> Error CS1501  No overload for method 'MapRoute' takes 4
>   arguments MyProject.ASP.NET 5.0   Startup.cs  81

I will be very grateful if I can get some advice about this, it would be nice to be able to use more than one HomeController in my system.

Answer (score 5):

Do you have the Area attribute on the class MyProject.Areas.MyArea.Controllers.HomeController.Index

something like

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;

namespace MyProject.Areas.MyArea.Controllers
{
    [Area("MyArea")]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

then the url /MyArea/Home/ should route to this controller, and just /Home/ should route to the home controller that's not in an area.